# Movie where a girl in a swing disappears when a solar flare hits

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

What's the name of the movie where there was a girl in a swing and a solar flare hit. The girl instantly disappears. There was also a scene where an incubator was made from a fishtank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I think it is called *[Where have all the people gone?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Have_All_The_People_Gone%3F)*

Comment: I did some googling, I think this is the correct answer, though I can't pin down the swing scene, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DISVnycTBvE) is is on youtube and here is a [pile of salt](http://cdn100.iofferphoto.com/img3/item/127/684/595/where-have-all-the-people-gone-1974-dvd-peter-graves-4be8.jpg) from the movie

Comment: I watched this on TV as a kid in the 70s. I've been YEARS trying to find the name of this!! Cheers!!

Answer (score 7):

The first part sounds similar to the [famous scene from Terminator 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BR_midwZ2f0), but I can't recall a scene from there with a fishtank incubator.  Is it possibly from two different movies?

Comment: No, this was a movie from the 70's.

Comment: Ok. This little girl, blonde Shirley Temple-like hairdo, was in a swing. The flare happened then she turned into a pile of salt. The dress she was wearing was lying on top of the salt pile that once was the girl. Does this clarify it?

Comment: @MartinNickell: Yes, it does.  It absolutely wasn't T2.  I don't know what it was, though.